# Launch on Boot on android 9 api 28 by java

Tags: java, android, webview, broadcastreceiver, android-app-bundle

In the emulator everything is working fine. When i install the build signed apk on the android tv, that's not working. In MainActivity file i am using webview
here is the code of android manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myboard" >

    <!-- To handle boot completes -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- To handle boot completes -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>

Boot receiver.java  file

package com.example.myboard;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
```

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // Launch your Android TV app here
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, com.example.myboard.MainActivity.class);
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

}

```
MainActivity.java file

package com.example.myboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the WebView in the layout
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        // Enable JavaScript (if required by your web app)
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // do something
            webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");


        // Load the URL of the web page you want to display

    }

    // Handle navigation with the back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

i searched on stack overflow geeksforgeeks, but i am not able to find the reason and why lauch on boot is not working on the android tv `your text`